# Can someone help me for convert this c# recursive function to java

Tags: java, c#, android

I have a c# function  and I want to translate my func to Java. But I'm making a mistake with this conversation and I cant figure it out.   Here is my C# code:

```
public bool ParantezKontrol(string input, int numOpen = 0)
    {
        if (numOpen < 0)
            return false;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            return numOpen == 0;

        char c = input[0];
        string rest = input.Substring(1);
        if (c == '(')
            return ParantezKontrol(rest, numOpen + 1);
        else if (c == ')')
            return ParantezKontrol(rest, numOpen - 1);
        else
            return ParantezKontrol(rest, numOpen);
    }
```

I couldnt realise `ParantezKontrol(string input, int numOpen = 0)` this definition and `return numOpen == 0;` this .

And here what i wrote Java code:

```
public boolean ParantezKontrol(String input, int numOpen){

    if(numOpen<0)   //numOpen=-1 olması durumunda parantez kapatılmayı unutmuştur. Bu durumda fonksiyon false değer gönderir.
        return false;
    if(input==null&&input.isEmpty()){

        return  true;
    }
    char c= input.charAt(0);

    String rest = input.substring(1);

    if(c == '(')
        return ParantezKontrol(rest,numOpen+1); //Girilen metinde '(' varsa fonksiyonu sağdan çağır
    else if (c==')')
        return ParantezKontrol(rest,numOpen-1); // ')' varsa soldan çağır
    else return ParantezKontrol(rest,numOpen);

}
```

can someone explain me where i'm making mistake and solve my problem please

Comment: `input==null&&input.isEmpty()` cannot be true. A string can't be null _and_ empty. If it is null, then your code will throw an exception.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a code converting tool

Comment: The C# version has `return numOpen == 0;`, but in your Java you put `return true;`

Comment: @Abion47 in java I cant define this function like ParantezKontrol(string input, int numOpen = 0) because there is no definition like numopen=0 in java.  That was I thought solution for that thing

Comment: @mybirthname I think you didnt read my question . I dont  want from you  to convert my code. I'm just asked a problem to if I solve this . If my friends help me, I'll be thankfull.

Comment: @enginear The lack of default argument values in Java shouldn't affect that return statement.

Comment: If you want us to solve some problem in your code, you should tell us what the problem is. E.g. expected output vs actual output

Comment: @enginear The alternative in Java to optional parameters is to overload the function and pass in the default value (that's basically what the C# compiler does anyway): `public boolean  ParantezKontrol(String input) { return ParantezKontrol(input, 0); }`

Comment: @GrantWinney I solved my problem with helps from vivek nuna my friend. Thank for asking . I'm very  thankfull :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public final boolean ParantezKontrol(String input)
{
    return ParantezKontrol(input, 0);
}

//Java does not support optional parameters. So you can overload this method
//ORIGINAL public bool ParantezKontrol(string input, int numOpen = 0)
public final boolean ParantezKontrol(String input, int numOpen)
{
        if (numOpen < 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (isNullOrEmpty(input))
        {
            return numOpen == 0;
        }

        char c = input.charAt(0);
        String rest = input.substring(1);
        if (c == '(')
        {
            return ParantezKontrol(rest, numOpen + 1);
        }
        else if (c == ')')
        {
            return ParantezKontrol(rest, numOpen - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            return ParantezKontrol(rest, numOpen);
        }
}
```

isNullOrEmpty and substring methods are not present in Java, So Write your own methods:

```
public static boolean isNullOrEmpty(String string)
{
    return string == null || string.length() == 0;
}
public static String substring(String string, int start, int length)
{
    if (length < 0)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Parameter length cannot be negative.");

    return string.substring(start, start + length);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helps my friend

Answer (score 0):

public bool ParantezKontrol(string input, int numOpen = 0) is only defining a default argument for numOpen, allowing "lazy" programmers to call  ParantezKontrol with only a string parameter - in your Java code both parameters are always required.

You should still be able to use return numOpen == 0;

This line should be if(input==null&&input.isEmpty()){

```
if(input==null || input.isEmpty()){
```

(Note C# method is IsNullOrEmpty not IsNullAndEmpty)